# Retrieve list from database

Tags: php, mysql, json

Without real knowledge the gambling remains & questions arise

I found a script where I`m able to tag people
but I don`t have any cluw how to retrieve a list from a database ???

```
<?php

  $term = isset($_GET['term']) ? $_GET['term'] : '';

  //TODO: you should retrieve this list from database

  //list of users

  $allUsers = array(
array('id' => 10 , 'title' => ' molendijk '),
array('id' => 20 , 'title' => ' rotterdam '),

    );

    $users = array();
    foreach ($allUsers as $user)
    {
if (stripos($user['title'], $term ) !== false) {
    $users[] = $user;
}
    }

    //generate output
    echo json_encode($users);

    ?>
```

On the line //TODO: you should retrieve this list from database
I tried simple this code to complete but it is not working

```
<?php
 // connect to the "tests" database
 $conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'comments', '123456', 'comments');
 // check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  // SELECT sql query
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user`  ORDER BY `id` DESC"; 
   // perform the query and store the result
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   // if the $result contains at least one row
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row from $result
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

//list of users I tried to add $row

```
   $allUsers = array(
array('id' => '. $row['id']. ' , 'title' => ' '. $row['user']. ' '),
array('id' => '. $row['id']. ' , 'title' => ' '. $row['user']. ' '),
```

I hope someone have some ideas for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of the code is the problem, you are trying to copy the sample code too closely when creating your `$allUsers` array.

In this code the `$allUsers[]` says to add the new row to the data you already have...

```
$allusers = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $allUsers[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'title' => $row['user']);
}
```

Comment: Nigel I added another Answer hope you can help me out

Comment: Please check the code in the answer - the line `$allUsers[]...` isn't the same.

Comment: I've also added `$allusers = array();` to make sure the array is initialised.

Comment: Nigel Ren thank you for all your support it is working now

Comment: Nigel I did what you said.... Furter don`t understand but Stackoverflow blocked me